# JUnit testing recursive method

Tags: java, junit

I made one class with recursive method that checks if two arrays are the same, now I want to test it with JUnit.
So my question would be:

**What method should I use to test for no value, negative value and limited value?**

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

ps: this is what I have done so far:

```
 @Test
 public void testOfTheTests(){
     System.out.println("Test");
     int[]a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
     int[]b={7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
     Boolean result = Main.equalsHelper2(a,b,0,6);
     Boolean expResult=true;
     // assertEquals(expResult,result);
     Assert.assertNotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: basically with unit testing you want to check the "public" api of your method and handle the internals as a blackbox (as long as they are not accessable from outside). Provide a test for each of your cases and assert on the expected values.

Comment: Didn't get the question. What does it means "check no value, negative value, limit value". could you please provide example?

Comment: @VladBochenin Dear Vlad, if my method gives no value, negative value and limit value, but that is why i am asking, my method isn't able to give negative  cause it shows only boolean, and limit value(ps this is my uni task to finish  that is why i am not shure what they want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have read about "no value, negative value and limited value" means, test all the different forms that your arrays can take, no value or negative doesn't apply to your case so you need to think of test cases that apply to your method.

Here are some test cases that you might want to add:

- One array is null
- Both arrays are null
- The arrays have different length
- The elements are in the same order in both
- The arrays have the same elements but in different order
- If the array indexes passed to your method are invalid
- ...
- ...

Here are two examples:

```
@Test
 public void testEqual(){
     int[]a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
     int[]b={7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
     Assert.assertEquals(a,b);
     Assert.assertTrue(Main.equalsHelper2(a,b,0,6));
}


@Test
 public void testDifferent(){
     int[]a={1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
     int[]b={7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
     Assert.assertNotEquals(a,b);
     Assert.assertFalse(Main.equalsHelper2(a,b,0,6));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**First : refactor the method name of the tested method.**

`equalsHelper2()` is really a bad chosen name.
Something like `isSameContent()` is better.
It is the same thing for the test method : `testOfTheTests()`.
It means everything and anything : it is really an anti pattern naming.

**Second : question yourself about the API of the method : input and output.**

For example : what the method should return if one or both arrays are null ? 
Should you throw an exception ? Return `false` ? And so for...

Other example : why using a `Boolean` and not a `boolean` as return type of the tested method?
Is `null` a valid return value ? If yes, why ? If not, use `boolean` rather.

To achieve it, the best way is proceeding with TDD : create incrementally a test method for each use case and give to each test method a relevant name : `isSameContent_with_empty_array()`, `isSameContent_with_same_content()`, `isSameContent_with_distinct_content()`, etc...
Implement it by starting by writing a first test method that specifies clearly the actual input and the expected output of the method and adapt the implementation consequently until the test passes.

Then, refactor if needed the implementation/test and go on with the next test method.

Comment: Thanks David, you also gave me great hint what to read and how to think when solving this type of problem .You guys are really treasure.i nowadays it is really much easier to became o try to became a programmer.I can't think how people just 20 years ago could solve some problem if they didn;t know where to start.So cheers and hope i didn;t  asked stupid question.